# How can I Select an IEnumerable over 2 Tables using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq

Given 3 Bussines Objects:

```
public class A 
{
    public long Id { get; set; } 
}

public class B
{
    public long ClassCId { get; set; }
    public string ClassBFirstString { get; set; }
}

public class C
{              
    public long Id { get; set; }           
    public long ClassAId { get; set; }
}
```

and a Method:

```
public IEnumerable<A> GetAllAbyClassBFirstStringFunction(string strg)
{

}
```

I would like to select all Objects of A´s  using LINQ having an ForeignKey(`ClassAId`) in Object C and Class B´s string (`ClassBFirstString`) equaling the methodParameter (`strg`).

There are 2 Entry Points I could use

first  is an `IEQueryable<A>` having all Objects of A lets call it _allObjectsOfA

second is an `IEQuaryable<B>` having all Objects of B´s lets call it _allObjetsOfB

How can this be done given the method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this mock-up:

```
List<A> ListOfA = new List<A>()
{
    new A { Id = 1 }, new A { Id = 2 }, new A { Id = 3 }
};

List<B> ListOfB = new List<B>()
{
    new B { ClassCId = 10, ClassBFirstString = "a"},
    new B { ClassCId = 11, ClassBFirstString = "b"},
    new B { ClassCId = 12, ClassBFirstString = "c"}
};

List<C> ListOfC = new List<C>()
{
    new C { Id = 10, ClassAId = 1},
    new C { Id = 11, ClassAId = 1},
    new C { Id = 11, ClassAId = 3},
    new C { Id = 12, ClassAId = 3}
};
```

this implementation of method `IEnumerable<A> GetAllAbyClassBFirstStringFunction`:

```
public static IEnumerable<A> GetAllAbyClassBFirstStringFunction(string strg)
{
    var q = from a in ListOfA
            join c in ListOfC on a.Id equals c.ClassAId
            join b in ListOfB on c.Id equals b.ClassCId
            where b.ClassBFirstString == strg
            select a;

    return q;
}
```

when invoked like this:

```
var q = GetAllAbyClassBFirstStringFunction("b");
```

return the following result:

`[0] = {ConsoleApplication1.A}` with `Id = 1`

`[1] = {ConsoleApplication1.A}` with `Id = 3`